# uwp switch data template - rebinding itemsource

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I'm making a win 10 universal app and I have two arrays of objects:

```
private ObservableCollection<Song> Songs;
private ObservableCollection<JonPlaylist> Playlists;
```

and a listview to display the data inside of them:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Song" x:Key="SongDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Name="ListSongName" Text="{x:Bind Title}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="ListArtist" Text="{x:Bind Artist}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:JonPlaylist" x:Key="PlaylistDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Name="ListSongName" Text="{x:Bind Title}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Page.Resources>
```

Listview:

```
<ListView Name="SongListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Songs}" IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemClick="SongListView_ItemClick" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SongDataTemplate}" />
```

The problem is that I want to be able to switch between the two arrays/collections which are of different data types.

I've been trying to accomplish this with the data templates as page resourses, and rebinding the listView.ItemSource and listView.ItemTemplate:

```
private void SwitchViewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            SongListView.ItemsSource = Playlists[0].GetType();
            SongListView.ItemTemplate = this.Resources.ElementAt(1);


}
```

However I do not know if this will work. Will it be better to utilize user controls and a visual state manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to rebind/re-template a single list view, why not have two list view controls and show/hide them as required?

I would very much recommend using the VisualStateManager to do this and employing the [x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2016/01/18/optimize-your-uwp-app-without-laziness/) to address performance concerns.

Let me know if you need further information about any on the above.

Comment: Thanks, changing the visibility value will do for now.

Comment: I'm getting a nullReferenceException whenever I try to manipulate the visibility of defered objects. Do I need to change the value of the loadstrategy before I can manipulate the visibility value? Keep in mind I'm also not using a statemanager at the moment.

Comment: Edit* I seem to be able to access the objects if I find them through this.FindName, although this seems very ugly as I have to intanciate a new variable every time. could a cleaner solution be found with the visual state manager

Comment: Have a read of the linked page. It explains why your getting null refs and how to resolve it (hint: use the visual state manager ;0)